# Javadocs loads very slow the first time I press CTRL+Q

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ 10+ ( I now have version 10.5) when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> the FIRST time I do that takes a very long time. More than minute maybe more than 2. After the first time it is ok, appears instantly.
Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Attach a thread dump when it happens: http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-260